# How to clone to home directory of the gitlab-runner user?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: docker 

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-prod:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker network create -d overlay reprox
  environment: master

test-prod:
  stage: test
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - runner  
  script:
    - echo "yolo"
  environment: master

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker  
  script:
    - docker stack deploy -c ./site1/docker-compose.yml site1
    - docker stack deploy -c ./site2/docker-compose.yml site2 
    - docker stack deploy -c ./site3/docker-compose.yml site3
    - docker stack deploy -c ./reverse-proxy/docker-compose.yml proxy  
  environment: master
```

I have the dummy echo job so it will clone to the worker but when the repo is cloned to any node it always clones to `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/random/0/docker/`

I don't need variables, I just want it to clone the repo in the `/home/gitlab-runner` directory for every gitlab-runner.

Comment: Why do you need that ? You can use the `CI_PROJECT_DIR` environment variable to reference the directory where the repository is cloned.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add that variable? Where in my yml file should it be and how would it look? I tried putting it under "image:docker" but that didn't do anything.

Comment: It depends : where do you need that variable ? The variable is available for all jobs

Comment: So I just add the variable under every job I want the repo to be in specific place?
Like this?
```
deploy-prod:
variables:
  CI_PROJECT_DIR: /home/gitlab-runner/
```

Comment: No it doesn't work like this. But, do you really need to know where the code is cloned ? If yes, why ?

Comment: I just want to clone the repo when running a pipline on any runner to `/home/gitlab-runner/` instead of `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/random/0/docker/`.  What is the best way to do that?

Comment: it doesn't work like that.  you need this encapsulation in order to run a lot of jobs together explain what you trying to achieve, it's sound like an XY problem 
 -  http://xyproblem.info/